# Correct mental model for a Javascript async function's 'await': generator's 'yield' vs. 'promise.then()'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, event-loop

Which of a generator's yield vs. promise.then() is a more* correct mental model for understanding 'await'?

Property comparison, inferred by stepping through the snippet below with a debugger:

await:

1. await does not pause/suspend the running async function’s execution. (The running async function ‘runs to completion’, returning a pending promise when the interpreter hits the 1st await. It’s then immediately removed from the call stack.)
2. await waits for the promise to settle.
3. `await expression` wraps the rest of a function's code in a microtask.

generator-yield:

1. yield pauses the running function’s execution. generator functions do not ‘run to completion’.
2. `yield promise` does ensure `promise` has settled prior to executing remaining code.
3. yield does not wrap or create a microtask.

promise.then(callback):

1. does not pause the running function’s execution.
2. waits for promise to settle before executing callback.
3. creates a microtask (callback)

```js
//promise returning function
function foo(whoCalled) {
   let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
     setTimeout( () => {
       console.log('resolving from setTimeout - called by: ' + whoCalled)
       resolve('resolve value') }, .1)
   })
   return p
}

//async await
async function asyncFunc() {
  await foo('async function')
  //rest of running function’s code…
  console.log('async function howdy')
}

//generator yield:
function* gen() {
   yield foo('generator function')
   //rest of running function’s code…
   console.log('generator function howdy')
}

//promise.then():
function thenFunc() {
   let r = foo('promise.then function').then(() => {
       //rest of running function’s code…
       console.log('promise.then() howdy')
   })
   return r
}

//main
function main() {

  //async await
  var a = asyncFunc() 
  console.log(a) //logs Promise { <pending> }
                 //the rest of the code following await foo() runs as a microtask runs once foo() resolves. The call stack was cleared.

  //generator
   var g = gen()
   console.log(g) // logs Object [Generator] {}
   var p = g.next().value
   console.log(p) //logs Promise { <pending> }
   g.next()       //the rest of the code following yield running gen function's code runs. call stack was not cleared.

   //promise.then()
   var x = thenFunc()
   console.log(x) //logs Promise { <pending> }
                   //the then(callback) microtask runs once foo() resolves. The call stack was cleared
}
main()
console.log('main is off the call stack - launch/startup macrotask completing. Event loop entering timer phase.')
```

And, going beyond this comparison, what is the accurate mental model of what `await` does under the hood?

await in latest ECMAScript spec for reference:
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#await

await in V8 source code: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/builtins/builtins-async-function-gen.cc#L252

Comment: `await` is like `.then()`

Comment: "*await does not pause/suspend the execution.*" and "*when the interpreter hits the 1st await. It’s then immediately removed from the call stack.*" do seem contradictory to me. What do you mean by that paragraph?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl can be helpful in figuring this out. Copy paste your code there and see how it simulates the await keyword.

Comment: @Bergi 1st quote = describes a pause in a function’s code for later resumption (not running to completion), vs. 2nd quote = describes wrapping the remainder of a function's code in a microtask, hitting the end curly brace and returning (run to completion).

Comment: @ToddChaffee Good tip. Is it correct to say the following? Transpiling can produce functionally equivalent vanilla Javascript. And while this may be helpful for inferring what's going on 'under the hood', it could be misleading? (for example: transpiled async await may not map to the ECMAScript async await spec)

Answer (score 5):

It's not one or the other. Actually it's both of them together: `async`/`await` = `yield` + `then` + a runner.

An `async function` does get suspended by the `await` keyword just like a generator `function*` does get suspended by the `yield` keyword. The mechanism of how the execution gets stopped and resumed in the middle of control flow statements is exactly the same.

What differs is how these continuations are driven, and what the functions return. A generator function creates a generator object when called, and you have to explicitly invoke the `next()` method from outside to run the code `yield` by `yield`. An async function on the other hand creates a promise, and manages the execution by itself. It doesn't wait for external `next()` calls but runs each asynchronous step as soon as possible. Instead of returning the yielded values from those `next()` calls, it does `Promise.resolve()` the awaited values to a promise, and calls its `then` method passing the continuation as the callbacks. Instead of signalling an "end of iteration" to the caller when reaching a `return`, it resolves the originally returned promise with the return value.

Comment: Hi Bergi, can you say more about the nature of "as soon as possible". `Async`/`await` so successfuly mimics synchronous code, there's a real danger that people misunderstand the non-blocking nature of an asyncFunction with await(s).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I've made it clear that the execution is still async.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. Is [v8 await source code](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/builtins/builtins-async-function-gen.cc#L243) the kind of thing you reference to determine this? Or ECMASpec abstract operations comparison [async function](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations) [generator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-generator-abstract-operations). Also, not sure what you mean by a 'runner' here?

Comment: @Bergi  Regarding: "...and calls its `then` method passing the continuation as the callbacks." I can't seem find where the `.then(continuation code callback)` is implemented in v8 await src code.

Comment: @AnonEq I learn from the spec about behaviour and from the V8 blog about optimisations. I don't read the code. The "runner" refers to the abstract idea of an entity that drives (runs) the code. In transpiled code, there e.g. is a function that takes care of dealing with the awaited promises and keeping things going by installing the then callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Promises and yield are not the easiest to grasp, especially not when you don't know how they work under the hood. So let's start with the basics. The first thing to understand is that Javascript is single threaded, which means that it can only do one thing at the same time. The way you are still able to multiple things at 'once' is because javascript has a thing called an event loop.

The event loop is basically looks something like this:

```
while(queue.waitForTasks()) {
   queue.performNextTask();
}
```

What the event loop does is check if there are new 'tasks' for Javascript to run. If there is a task. then it gets executed until there are no more tasks left to execute. And it will wait for its new task. These tasks are stored in something that is called a queue.

**Promises, Async/Await**

Now we understand how Javascript processes the different tasks. How does it work with promises, and async/await? A `promise` is nothing more than a task, or in the case of Javascript something that holds a task, that will be added to the queue and executed once all tasks before it have been executed. The `.then()` is a way of providing a callback to your promise that gets executed once your resolve callback is called.

the `await [something]` keyword tells Javascript, hey put the next `[something]` on the end of your queue, and get back to me once that `[something]` has a result to give.

A function that has the `async` keyword is basically telling Javascript: 'This function is a promise, but execute it immediately'.

The flow of a async function is easiest to grasp/demonstrate with two different async functions A and B like this:

```
const A = async () => {
    console.log(A: Start);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        await (async () => console.log('A: ' + i));
    }
    console.log('A: Done');
}
```

```
const B = async () {
    console.log(B: Start);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        await (async () => console.log('B: ' + i));
        await (async () => {/* A task without output */});
    }
    console.log('B: Done');
}
```

When you are calling your functions with await like this:

```
console.log('Executing A');
await A();
console.log('Executing B');
await B();
```

it would result in:

```
Executing A
A: Start
A: 0
A: 1
A: 2
A: Done
Executing B
B: Start
B: 0
B: 1
B: 2
B: Done
```

and running:

```
console.log('Executing A');
A();
console.log('Executing B');
B();
```

would result in:

```
Executing A
A: Start       Note: still gets ran before Executing B
Executing B
B: Start
A: 0
B: 0
A: 1
A: 2           Note: A: 2 first because another task in B was put in the queue
A: Done
B: 1
B: 2
B: Done
```

Understanding this might help to better understand the flow of your application.

**yield**

The `yield` keyword is similar to `await` in the sense that an 'outside force' controls when it continues the flow of the function. In this case not the completion of the promise task, but the `generator.next()` function

Comment: A promise is not a task, and it does not get put on the event queue. It's the task of executing the `then` callback that gets put on the queue *when the promise fulfills*.

Comment: Okay maybe I should change my phrasing a bit, since it is not very exact. As you might have noticed. I'll do that later though, this already took a while to write haha

Comment: @SoftwarePerson "A promise is nothing more than a task." Incorrect. Might instead say 'a promise is nothing more than an object representing an eventual return/resolve value'.
"await [something] keyword tells Javascript, hey put the next [something] on the end of your queue, and get back to me once that [something] has a result to give." Incorrect. [something] is executed immediately, and synchronously. It's subsequent function code that is wrapped in a microtask.

Comment: @SoftwarePerson "A function that has the async keyword is basically telling Javascript: 'This function is a promise, but execute it immediately'." Incorrect. The async keyword is interpreted as, 'this function returns a promise, and await can be used in the func body'.

Comment: The code doesn't generate that result. By `await (async () => console.log('A: ' + i))` you're awaiting on *definition* of anonymous function which is indeed a non-thenable object. You need to execute the anonymous function: `await ((async () => console.log('A: ' + i))())`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to the correct mental model here, though I would really like to know.

But I found this interesting

Kyle Simpson author of 'You Don't Know JS' chimed in on how await works on r/Javascript reddit - [source](https://www.reddit.com/user/getify):

> "This is entirely incorrect. Generators do not run-to-completion, and
>   most engine implementations of async-await actually treat them like
>   generators. When a yield is encountered, the generator is locally
>   paused... literally. Await uses the same approach."
>
> "No, this is all incorrect nonsense. Most engines treat async-await
>   like a generator, which definitely does localy pause at a yield.
>   **Wrapping promise.then() around subsequent code would be one of the most naive and inefficient ways to implement await.** Even if an
>   engine did that (most don't) that doesn't mean that's the proper
>   mental. model. Local pausing like yield is the proper mental model."

But when I personally look at the ECMA Script spec myself and walk though code with the vscode nodejs debugger, await seems much more analogous to .then()